# Is there anyway I can spell check my notebook in Azure Data Studio or VS Code

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, azure-data-studio

I am really enjoying using Jupyter notebooks in Azure Data Studio, especially the markdown sections between the code.

I want to distribute the notebook to my client, however, I am a terrible speller and rely heavily on spellcheck normally.

Is there anyway to enable spell check in Azure Data Studio for the MD?
Or is there a solution in VSCode?

Tahnks